# Reverse a Span in NetStandard 2

Tags: c#, arrays, string, .net-standard-2.0

I need to reverse a `Span<Char>`, and it would be easy if I were using NetStandard 2.1.

I could use [MemoryExtensions.Reverse(Span)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.reverse?view=net-5.0), but unfortunately, it's not supported in the version I am using.

I tried to copy the code from the [repository](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/MemoryExtensions.cs), but it uses some language features that don't exist in the NetStandard 2.0.

I don't mind using a less optimized implementation because it's not often used in my code. Still, I cannot convert it to string and then reverse it because I cannot handle garbage collection triggers in this implementation.

How to reverse a `Span<Char>` without converting to string or upgrading the NetStandard version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why not a simple for loop, if being super efficient is not criticial?

```cs
Span<int> x = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.AsSpan();
for (int i = 0, j = x.Length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
{
    var temp = x[i];
    x[i] = x[j];
    x[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: I don't know! Seems reasonable, its just an array, isnt it? Its ReadonlySpan but that could change, thanks.

Comment: btw, the C# language features that you mentioned are most likely orthogonal to .NET Standard version and instead your C# language version. The latest version of `System.Memory` still supports .NET Standard 2.0. So if you can't update to latest version of the NuGet package, and for some reasons your current project can't use the latest C# language versions, but still want to use a more efficient implementation, you should be able to build a separate package with latest language version targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and import it in your other project that uses lower language version.

Comment: No, the problem is not the language version, it's because these features exists only in NetStandard 2.1

Answer (score 2):

Install latest [`System.Memory`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) NuGet package, and `MemoryExtensions.Reverse` method will be available for you to use.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only available at NetStandard 2.1

Comment: The package targets .net standard 2.0 and can be installed to any project targeting .net standard 2.0. If you install the package you will have the method available regardless of targeting version. The Microsoft docs says it’s available in .net standard 2.1 without having to install an additional nuget package, not the method can’t be used.

Comment: I have installed the package. There is no Span.Reverse into this package when referenced from a NetStandard 2.0